# Numbering a theorem by section number

Tags: numbering

I'm creating some lecture notes for my class using the `book` class, it is structured by chapters and sections. In some of my sections I want to add homework (and in some, I don't). I've been accomplishing this with the `amsthm` package:

```
\newtheorem{homew}{Homework} 
\begin{homew} Solve for $x$
\begin{enumerate}
\item $1=x+2$
\item $1=x-2$
\end{homew}
```

However, I want this homework to be numbered by the section it is in, so I can call back to it. So for example I want my document to look like this:

> Chapter 1
>
> Section 1
>
> Homework 1
>
> Section 2
>
> Section 3
>
> Section 4
>
> Homework 4

And so on.

My question is two-fold:

1. How to accomplish this? The counter options when creating a newtheorem don't do it. I don't want the Homework to be numbered as Homework 4.1 (there's no Homework 4.2, so what's the point?), and giving it its own counter doesn't work since then I get Homework 2 in Section 4, which I don't want either.
2. Is there a more elegant way of doing this? I'm really new to LaTeX so I appreciate any help.

Comment: what if you add `\renewcommand*{\thehomew}{\arabic{section}}` right after the definition of the `homew` environment?

Comment: Hey, that works for me!, Thank you pluton. If anyone else wishes to help me answer question 2, I'd be grateful. It just seems like newtheorem isn't the best tool to add homework but I'm new to this and for now it will do.

Comment: I think it is a good idea to use the `amsthm` package for this. There might be other ways but this one is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `tcolorbox` solution for a nicer output and using `\thesection` as counter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcbtheorem{homew}{Homework}{title={\tcbtitle \thesection},enhanced jigsaw,boxrule=0pt,coltitle=black,
  sharp corners,colback=white,colbacktitle=white!40!yellow}{homew}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{homew}{Solve for $x$}{first}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $1=x+2$
\item $1=x-2$
\end{enumerate}
\end{homew}

\section{Second}
\begin{homew}{Solve for $x$ and $y$}{second}
\begin{align}
  1 &= x+y \\
  1 &= x-y
\end{align}
\end{homew}

\section{Another section}    

\begin{homew}{Solve for $x$ and $y$ and $z$}{third}
\begin{align}
  1 &= x+y-z \\
  1 &= x-y-z \\
  1 &= x+y+z
\end{align}
\end{homew}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that looks very pretty, I will definitely experiment with it.

Comment: @TheFourthMan: You're welcome to use it!

Comment: Is there a way so that the 'homew' environment absorbs enumerate? I find that more often than not I'm inputing both.

Comment: @TheFourthMan: What do you mean by 'absorb'? It should provide you with `enumerate` automatically?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the easiest way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}

\newtheorem{homew}{Homework} 
\def\thehomew{\thesection}

\begin{document}
\section{Some Section}

\begin{homew} Solve for $x$
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $1=x+2$
        \item $1=x-2$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{homew}

\section{Some Other Section}

\begin{homew} Solve for $y$
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $1=y+2$
        \item $1=y-2$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{homew}

\section{New Section}

\section{Last Section}

\begin{homew} Solve for $z$
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $1=z+2$
        \item $1=z-2$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{homew}

\setcounter{section}{99}
\section{Just Kidding}

\begin{homew} Solve for $w$
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $1=w+2$
        \item $1=w-2$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{homew}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico Oops, at first I thought op was asking for something else and I forgot to remove that line.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses the `\AtBeginEnvironment` macro of the `etoolbox` package to modify the counter variable that's associated with the `hw` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}     % Or: \usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{hw}{Homework} % Set up "Homework" environment

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{hw}{% % Modify "hw" counter variable
   \setcounter{hw}{\value{section}}
   \addtocounter{hw}{-1}}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\begin{hw} abc \end{hw}
\section{B}
\section{C}
\begin{hw} def \end{hw}
\section{D}
\begin{hw} ghi \end{hw}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. One of my bad postings -- apparently I've lost my sense of TeX considering the huge criticism during the last days/weeks :-(. Thanks for informing me.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - What "huge criticism"? :-(

Comment: Too long for a comment and I should replace `huge` by `constant`, perhaps. Don't worry about that.